# How can I identify two substrings from a list that make up one unique substring from a larger list into a new dictionary?

Tags: python, json, string, loops, substring

I have a large list of unique strings (~1000), for instance: [bbbhbbbh, jjjhhssa, eeeffus,...]

And a smaller list of sub-string pairs (~50) that make up each of these unique strings: [bbbh, jjjh, hssa, eeef, fus,...]

I want to create a function that takes the large unique string list (~1000) as an argument and returns a dictionary with the unique string and the corresponding values of its two unique sub-strings.

For example:

```
result = {'bbbhbbbh': 'bbbh/bbbh', 
            'jjjhhssa': 'jjjh/hssa', 
            'eeeffus': 'eeef/fus',...}
```

I've tried with a for loop but I am not able to print the unique strings with duplicates, I am wondering if there is a more concise way with list comprehension along with returning the two corresponding values that make up the unique string? I only want to use the json package at this point and solve this without importing any new packages. Thank you for any help with this.

My current loop and output:

```
result = []    

for string in pair_list:
    matches = []
    for substring in sub_list:
        if substring in string:
            matches.append(substring)
    if matches:
        result.append(matches)

print(result)

[['bbbh'], ['jjjh', 'hssa'], ['eeef', 'fus'],...
```

Answer (score 0):

AS per your output format I think you are expecting a dictionary kind of object.
Where Long string is Key and all matched sub string is value. Just modifying your code, I added a dict object to store the result and append the sub string to the values. Since we also need to get repeated sub string we can use count method and string.

**Code:**

```
pair_list = ["bbbhbbbh", "jjjhhssa", "eeeffus"]
sub_list = ["bbbh", "jjjh", "hssa", "eeef", "fus"]
pair_mapping_result = dict() 

for pair_string in pair_list:
    for sub_string in sub_list:
        if sub_string in pair_string:
            matched_sub_pairs = "/".join([sub_string] * pair_string.count(sub_string))
            pair_mapping_result[pair_string] = (r"{}/{}".format(pair_mapping_result[pair_string], 
                                                               matched_sub_pairs) 
                                                if pair_mapping_result.get(pair_string) else matched_sub_pairs)

print(pair_mapping_result)
```

**Output**

```
{'bbbhbbbh': 'bbbh/bbbh', 'jjjhhssa': 'jjjh/hssa', 'eeeffus': 'eeef/fus'}
```

We can do it using a dict comprehension

**Code**

```
{pair_string: "/".join(["/".join([sub_string] * pair_string.count(sub_string)) 
                        for sub_string in sub_list \
                        if sub_string in pair_string]) \
                        for pair_string in pair_list}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you for this! The only issue is in the sub_list there is only one instance of "bbbh" and one of the issues I am running into is being able to somehow print the {'bbbhbbbh': 'bbbh/bbbh',... with regards to this

Comment: In the sub_list there are two 'bbbh' so only there is two bbbh in output

Comment: In my original sub_list there is only one ‘bbbh’ so it is still not original.

Comment: @kenai now does it look right?

Comment: Yes but I am attempting to have it return {'bbbhbbbh': 'bbbh'/‘bbbh’,… sorry I should have been more specific, this is the difficulty of this problem for me at the moment.

Comment: @kenai why should it be there twice?

Comment: To show that it requires two of the same substrings to make the original string

Comment: @kenai suppose if the large text is 'sfsfs' and smaller text is 'sfs' what will be the output?

Comment: {‘sfsfs’: ‘sfs’/‘fs’,… assuming in our smaller substring list we also have not only ‘sfs’ but ‘fs’ as well.

Comment: hey thank you! I will take a crack at this tomorrow. I am also going to try a different approach and create some sort of hashmap/sorted dictionary that organizes the sub_list by character count (the full sub-string list has char count ranging from 2 to 6) and does some basic arithmetic to narrow down the possible sub-string options- then we wont have to face this (O)n^2 time complexity either. If I figure this out this week, I'll post/add to my solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Previously in the code it was not searching for its duplicate in the list items. Once it gets the desired substring in the main string it passes onto another. But now its finding multiple duplicate through reggex finditer method.

```
pair_list= ['bbbhbbbh', 'jjjhhssa', 'eeeffus', 'aaaabbbh', 'ccccdddd','eeefff']

sub_list = ['bbbh', 'jjjh', 'hssa', 'eeef', 'fus']

import re
result = []    
for string in pair_list:
    matches = []
    for substring in sub_list:
        for duplicate in re.finditer(substring, string):
            matches.append(substring)
    if matches:
        result.append(matches)

print(result)
```

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Thank you!! I am trying to solve this with only the json package and no other packages used.